# Relay to Tesla Coil

Tags: relay, high-voltage, high-current, tesla-coil, hvdc

If you take apart a Relay (small, mine is  out of a printer) and open it up there is a tall coil of wire. Are you able to use that coil of wire to make a HV generator or Tesla coil of a sort?

Comment: Yes, you could use the core to create a high voltage spike, but I'd suggest probably only a few hundred volts (its limited by the inter layer voltage limits). Best potential to produce high voltage for it would be to wrap another layer of wire over the coil and feed that with a pulse from say a capacitive discharge circuit.

Comment: It would be incredibly impractical for a Tesla coil. The wire is very thin, meaning the resistance will be very high. Additionally, if you were to scale down the width of the wire vs. required turns/inductance for the secondary coil, the voltage you would get at the output would barely be worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. However it's not clear from your question whether you mean use the coil of the wire, or the wire. There are three ways I can think of.

1) Use the relay itself as a 'buzzer'. This was a popular way to get high voltage for valve amplifiers from batteries. Arrange the relay contacts to be normally closed, and put them in series with the coil. The relay energises, breaks its supply, opens, so re-energises etc. The back emf spike is rectified and used as the high voltage output. You are limited here to a few hundred volts, due to the contacts sparking. A caapcitor across the contacts can help control the rate of rise of voltage, so reduce the sparking.

2) Use the coil of wire as a ready-wound secondary, whether still on the relay or removed from it. Wind a few turns of primary on there and a few more turns for a feedback secondary, and make a transformer. Look up ZVS driver. You are limited here to several 100 volts due to the multi-layer construction of the coil, which may arc across. You may scrape 1000v, but unfortunately once you've found the limit, you've fried the insulation.

3) Unwind the coil of wire, and re-wind it into a (small) Tesla secondary. As it's single layer, you have a much higher voltage withstanding. Complete your tesla coil in the normal way. While a really small tesla coil will not produce neighbourhood-shattering sparks, you can still get some interesting glows, light gas-discharge tubes remotely, that sort of fun.